# OSX Minimize trigger area to show dock

Tags: macos, dock

I have my dock auto-hiding and when I hover my pointer in the **area** where the dock **would have been** it pops up again.

I want it to show when I hit the **bottom of the screen** with my pointer, not just the area where it would have been. The problem I have is that if I've got a window with the bottom end in that area and try to click or selecting something the dock shows up instead.

So if my dock is 50 pixels high, if my pointer is within 50 px from the bottom the dock will show up. But I want it to show up when I've got the pointer at the last pixel at the bottom of the screen.

Any tips? I haven't found many others, if any, that have the same problem or want the same thing so it feels I'm doing something wrong here... :)

Cheers.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but one solution could be to move the dock to the side of the screen?

Comment: Have you tried bringing the Dock back (Cmd+Alt+D) and re-hide it again? While I never had this particular issue, maybe something got stuck thinking that the Dock is shown instead of hidden.